# Parsing OBJ file having multiple objects

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, wavefront

On reading through the OBJ file format, I realized that there are several other attributes like Sub-objects (`-o`), Groups (`-g`) etc.

I am having trouble understanding how to parse these other parameters (if necessary). Should I load the vertices and faces data of every (`-o`) into separate VAOs?

Also, in that case, how will the rotation of the whole object work? Will all Sub-objects start rotating about their own centers?

How to make the multiple sub-objects rotate in unison like a single object and still have independent control over each whenever necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Should I load the vertices and faces data of every (-o) into separate VAOs?**

Basically yes.  Each object (-**o**) or smoothing group (-**g** or -**s**) is essentially a separate part of the overall *model*.  So you should be creating a separate renderable mesh for each group.

> Generally the vertex data (vertices, normals, texture coordinates) is not shared between models, but there's nothing in the OBJ format to say they couldn't be AFAIK.

**How to make the multiple sub-objects rotate in unison like a single object and still have independent control over each whenever necessary?**

This is more of a design question.  Assuming you have some sort of tree-like scene-graph then you would create a root node for the entire OBJ model and attach separate nodes for each group.  To rotate the whole model you apply a transform to the root node.  As far as I know the OBJ format does not specify transformations, rotations, etc.